# Querying Table vs Querying Subquery of Same Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with some very old legacy code, and I've seen a few queries that are structured like this

```
SELECT
    FieldA,
    FieldB,
    FieldC
FROM
    (
     SELECT * FROM TABLE1
    )
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON...
```

Is there any advantage to writing a query this way?

This is in Oracle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: I belive the outside query is bringing the result of the `LEFT JOIN` and you **cant** get that direct from the table, what is `FIELDS`? you use it instead of `*`?

Comment: Is it really just a straight `SELECT * FROM TABLE1` as the subquery? I can't imagine any good reason for doing this. At best it will function the same, at worst it makes the query difficult to read.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think you've misread the question. The query the OP has put involves a subquery that selects everything from table1. Columns from the left outer join would be available regardless of whether you replaced the subquery with the table itself.

Comment: @DixieFlatline the only reasons I can think that someone would have written the code in this way is if in previous versions the subquery was more complicated (e.g. it had a where clause) and when that was removed, they didn't bother replacing the subquery with the table name directly. Or maybe they expected to add a filter at a later date. There's no advantage to it at all, other than perhaps saving a few keystrokes at a later date.

Comment: @Boneist I think we need more information. I dont know if `FieldA,  FieldB, FieldC` are from `Table1` or `Table2`, That is why Im not sure if you need the subquery or not. If all fields are from Table1, then the `LEFT JOIN` and the subquery are usuless

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the presence of the left outer join is not in question here; I believe the OP is talking about the subquery. If you do `select * from (select * from table1)` that is the same as doing `select * from table1`. You'd be able to access all the columns in table1 whether you used that subquery or not.

Comment: @Boneist Ohh i see it now, Yes, that is a bad thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would seem to be no advantage to using a subquery like this.  The reason may be a historical relic, regarding the code.

Perhaps once upon a time, there was a more complicated query there.  The query was replaced by a table/view, and the author simply left the original structure.

Similarly, once upon a time, perhaps a column needed to be calculated (say for the outer query or `select`).  This column was then included in the table/view, but the structure remained.

I'm pretty sure that Oracle is smart enough to ignore the subquery when optimizing the query.  Not all databases are that smart, but you might want to clean-up the code.  At the very least, such as subquery looks awkward.

Answer (score 0):

As a basic good practice in SQL, you should not code a full-scan from a table (`SELECT * FROM table`, without a `WHERE` clause), unless necessary, for performance issues.

In this case, it's not necessary: The same result can be obtained by:

```
SELECT
    Fields
FROM
    TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON...
```